# At what level are nonce's required to be injected within a cycle?

Tags: node, rpc, nonce

Nonces are to be revealed/injected in the cycle after which they are tied to their block. If you bake a block in cycle 4, and the level % 32 is 0, then you are required to reveal the nonce seed in cycle 5.

The question is, within cycle 5, can you reveal at any of the 4096 blocks or must you reveal within the first 4? First 10? In using block explorers, I see most reveals happen before level-in-cycle 4. I tried revealing a nonce about 1/2 way through the cycle and received `proto.006-PsCARTHA.nonce.unexpected` error.

Answer (score 2):

You can reveal seed nonce at any level in the following cycle.

Example: [level 3590 of 4096](https://tzkt.io/802311/anonymous).

You see most revelations within the first blocks because the native baking software simply tries to push the revelation operation ASAP. However, it would be much better to inject revelation in your own block in order to earn extra rewards.

As for the `proto.006-PsCARTHA.nonce.unexpected`, [according to the docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/errors.html) that error literally means "The provided nonce is inconsistent with the committed nonce hash.". So the problem is likely in your nonce value, that you are trying to reveal.

Comment: Confusing as I tried injecting a nonce revelation about 1000 blocks in and got the error noted in my post.

Comment: How did you try to inject it? Manually? Are you sure you had a right to reveal a nonce? Are you sure you hadn't already revealed a nonce, when were trying to inject it?

Comment: Yes, manually. Constructed the operation (same watermark as an endorsement) signed and injected, got error. I believe the error message is different if you try to reveal a nonce that's already been revealed.

Comment: Are you sure that the block that contains the hash of the nonce you are trying to reveal is indeed part of the chain?

Comment: @utdrmac I'm curious, where did you get the 32 bytes nonce, when constructing `seed_nonce_revelation` operation?

Comment: This is the block I baked, in which I included the nonce: https://carthage.tzkt.io/764352 C373. It is now C374 and I'm trying to reveal the hash 801fb63ac40b968612e26fa5017da061215a1026cf49e5cf1185da59359a2eba which should match that nonce. But I'm still getting same error. I'll try to gather the JSON of the reveal and post it.

Comment: @utdrmac I've tried to reveal that hash and have got an error "This nonce revelation is invalid (inconsistent with the committed hash)". Then I checked the sources, https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_001_PtCJ7pwo/lib_protocol/nonce_storage.ml#L69-71 and realized that "unexpected nonce" actualy means "invalid nonce" :) So, the problem is in your nonce value.

Comment: Ugh. What a pain that the error message is incorrect. Ok. Thank you for investigating that. I'll try some to figure out why my nonce value is wrong.